# Accessing all class variables in a container without a loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, containers

I have a list 'users' that contains objects of the class 'user'. Each user has a list 'records', which contains objects of the class 'record'. Each record has a datetime variable describing when that specific record was made.

I would like to create a list that contains all the datetime variables of the records across all users. I've done that using nested loops, but I guess that there's a smarter method?

```
# Add all dates to one list
dateList = list()
for i in range(0,nUsers):
    for j in range(0, len(users[i].records)):
        dateList.append(users[i].records[j].datetime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get rid of the indexing and iterate over the objects itself.

```
dateList = list()
for user in users:
    for record in user.records:
        dateList.append(record.datetime)
```

Then you see that you can use a list comprehension.

```
dateList = [record.datetime for user in users for record in user.records]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list-comprehension is probably what you mean.

```
date_list = [r.datetime for user in users for r in user.records]
```

Python variables should be lower_case_with_underscores and not CamelCase.

Also, iterating in Python does not require using indexes. You can iterate directly on the items.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to use loops, but you can do it in a single list comprehension:

```
date_list = [record.datetime for user in users for record in user.records]
```

Note that even using separate loops, in Python you should *never* iterate over a range and then use the index to get the element; always iterate over the thing itself, so `for user in users` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two nested list comprehensions:

```
date_list = [record.datetime for record in
                [user.record for user in user_list]]
```